# Wordpress Function Only Apply To Single Page (Post Thumbnail)

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I am trying to control my post thumbnail size on two different pages.

I am using

```
set_post_thumbnail_size( 875, 175 );
```

To control the size on my index page. And then when they open the post I want the single.php to have the full size image.

Comment: using the_post_thumbnail( array(875,175) ); in your post query. you have not using array in your code so replace code to this.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`get_the_post_thumbnail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail), you would call this in your single.php template and specify the size you want.

Answer (score 0):

You add an image size with `add_image_size();` ([documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size)) and then call on the thumbnail size in your theme with `the_post_thumbnail();`. You can add as many image sizes as you would like.

So lets create two sizes with

```
add_image_size( 'home-thumb', 330, 175, true);
add_image_size( 'single-thumb', 875, 300, true );
```

This will add them and you can call them using using `the_post_thumbnail('single-thumb');` since you want the single page to have the full image size you can just use `the_post_thumbnail();`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(is_single()) { 
    set_post_thumbnail_size( 875, 175 ); 
} else {
    set_post_thumbnail_size( other dimensions here ); 
}
```